# <h:graphicImage > tag not changing image

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, facelets

I'm displaying the data from database in  and on one particular column if i mouseover i have given one jQuery popup it will hover and display the details. My problem is on mouseover any row its not changing the image its showing the first row image. 
I'm using this tag to display the image

```
<ui:repeat var="u" value="#{userdataList}" varStatus="status">     

        <a href="#" class="popper" data-popbox="pop1" onmouseover="getValue('#{u.userId}')">    
           <h:graphicImage id="image" alt="user image" url="/ServletToDisplayImage?userId=#{u.userId}" width="36" height="36"/>
        </a>
        <div id="pop1" class="popbox">
            <h2>Member details</h2>
            <h:graphicImage id="photoimage" alt="user image" url="/ServletToDisplayImage?userId=#{u.userId}" width="100" height="100"/>

        </div>

</ui:repeat>
```

This is placed in  and will be hidden on mouse over it will display.The #{u.userId} need to change ,how this can be achieved?

OR can i pass the value to this query string from javascript everytime on mouseover?

For Hover i'm refering this link below

http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/jquery-hover-box

I tried like onmouseover="getValue('#{u.userId}') get the value and able to set to a hidden field and its changinf eachtime from a javascript function.But how to set this as values for querystring .

Comment: Please share your full code

Comment: @user3489875 shared code can you look into it.